# Is it possible to transform a shared library into a static one?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I think it is not feasible or there is no tools enabling this but in theory all needed material is there in a shared library plus what is on the operating system to generate a static library from a shared library.

So do you think it is theorically feasible and if not why?

My issue is with libkrb5 which only provides shared libraries on ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: You can re-compile it as a static

Comment: @Satish Do you have an example?

Comment: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.0/postlfs/mitkrb.html

Comment: @Satish Actually building libkrb5 only generates dynamic libs. I don't see any way of compiling static libs.

Comment: did you compile with --enable-static option?

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-compile-a-static-binary-697658/